# ML algorithms that adapt to the given input data (whether its given or not given)?

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for a machine learning algorithm that can handle input data that has missing parameters.

Example:
A model is trained using data that consist 10 input parameter. Data with 2 of the 10 parameters having value of NaN is used to make prediction.

Is there any machine learning algorithm that can make prediction with this data or do I have to process the NaN value in any way first? Is there a machine learning algorithm that has built-in function that processes NaN values?

---

Maybe my question wasn´t detailled enough. I do have all data needed to train the model and i do know how to handle data before training in terms of missing values. My question was meant differently. Once i´ve trained the model and i would use the model in production, live data, and it occurs that only get, for example, values of 8 of the 10 features that i trained the model with, is there an algorithm that can still perform a prediction? My first thought would be setting up a default value for each of the 10 values and set this value if i would receive a Nan value but i hoped for an algorithm that is able to handle this itself. So that the model is able to replace a Nan value with best suited replacement (mean, back-fill or what ever)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the ML algorithm can still make predictions with the available data however you should consider handling missing data so that the model trains better.

There are several ways of handling missing values in your data before you train your model. Some of the methods you can try are

1. Ignore the data row
2. Back-fill or forward-fill to propagate next or previous values
   respectively:

   - for back fill dataframe.fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True)
   - for forward-fill dataframe.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
3. Replace with some constant value outside fixed value range-999,-1
   etc
4. Replace with mean, median value
5. Isnull feature Adding new feature isnull indicating which rows have
   missing values for this feature. By doing this the tree based
   methods it can now understand that there was a missing value. The
   downside is that we double the number of features.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what software package you use and how you represent your features. `NaN` might be interpreted differently across machine learning packages (scikit learn, weka, vowpal wabbit, tensorflow, etc.)

You're basically describing a dataset that is somewhat sparse. You can either try to extrapolate/interpolate those values (if at all possible), or you can set them to 0.

Comment: Thanks, is there some sort of documentation on how the different ML libraries (scikit, tesnorflow,...) do handle NanN values? Unfortunately i could not find any sources.